# Truffle Deployment failed

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

## 1_initial_migration.js

### Deploying 'Calculator'

> transaction hash:    0xb214606988ee76e84ca853aa70eee13ee55ffc29eb2baecc20729f49e2255561
> ✖ Blocks: 52           Seconds: 758
> *** Deployment Failed ***

"Calculator" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment
parameters.)

- Block limit:  30000000 (0x1c9c380)
- Gas sent:     5500000 (0x53ec60)

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

first i only had one demo contract for a simple calculator it was working fine alone, then i build one more big smart contract for the Job posting on a freelance app, then i got the error "ran out of gas". Then i commented out the JobContract migration and ran **truffle migrate --network goerli**, i had 0.3294 goerliETH, it kept on running for 20 mins till it crashed at block 52 saying ran out of gas.
Q1. how do i set the correct gas price
Q2. how do i see blocks ( tried truffle console as well for this)

Answer (score 0):

this setting will work for you

```
const keys = require("./keys.json");


goerli: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(keys.PRIVATE_KEY, keys.INFURA_GOERLI_URL),
      network_id: 5,
      gas: 5500000,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
    },
```

I keep the PRIVATE_KEY, and INFURA_GOERLI_URL in "keys.json" file because you need those only for deployment, and then make sure you delete the contents. make sure you import them correctly

```
 console.log(keys.sPRIVATE_KEY)
 console.log(keys.INFURA_GOERLI_URL)
```